# Relationship Between Area in Triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Here is the question and diagram]

I understand the relationship between base lengths and area.

Letting $$AB = 4x, BC=5x, ED = y, DC = 7y$$

Since the ratio of the bases is $$5x:9x  $$  the ratio of areas would be $$25x^2:81x^2$$ therefore 
$$25:81, 25+81=106.$$
Yet the answer is wrong (by one)! Where is my thought process incorrect??

Comment: Your method only applies to *similar* triangles (exact same shape, only different in scale). For triangles of the same height, different base (or vice versa), use the method in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let area of $\triangle AED = x$. Then area of $\triangle ADC = 7x$ (same height, consider  the ratio of bases).

By the same reasoning (considering that the ratio of areas of $\triangle BDC$ to $\triangle ADC$ is $5:9$), area of $\triangle BDC = (\frac 59) \cdot (7x) = \frac{35x}{9}$

So the ratio between areas of $\triangle BDC$ and $\triangle AED = \frac{35}{9}x: 8x = 35:72$. Since it's in the lowest terms, the required answer is $35 + 72 = 107$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @PhilTheLawyer No prob, mate.